# combining replacer and fields in json.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

How would I use white-list of fields and a replace function at the same time when using json.stringify?

- [How to stringify objects through JSON's replacer function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280322/how-to-stringify-objects-through-jsons-replacer-function)

explains how to use a field list.

- [Hide null values in output from JSON.stringify()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41115702/hide-null-values-in-output-from-json-stringify)

Has an answer for filtering null values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41116529/1497139

Based on that code snippet i am trying:

```js
var fieldWhiteList=['','x1','x2','children'];

let x = {
  'x1':0,
  'x2':null,
  'x3':"xyz", 
  'x4': null,
   children: [
     { 'x1': 2, 'x3': 5},
     { 'x1': 3, 'x3': 6}
   ]
}

function replacer(key,value) { 
  if (value!==null) {
    if (fieldWhiteList.includes(key)) 
      return value;
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(x, replacer,2));
```

And the result is:

```
{
  "x1": 0,
  "children": [
    null,
    null
  ]
}
```

Which is not what I expected. I would have expected the x1 values for the children to show up and not null values.

**How could i achieve the expected result?**

see also [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf_bitplan_com/znjp3d7a/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By adding some debug output to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf_bitplan_com/znjp3d7a/11/)

```js
function replacer(key,value) { 
  if (value!==null) {
    if (fieldWhiteList.includes(key)) 
      return value;
  }
  console.log('ignoring '+key+'('+typeof (key)+')');
}
```

I got the output:

```
ignoring x2(string) 
ignoring x3(string) 
ignoring x4(string) 
ignoring 0(string) 
ignoring 1(string) 
ignoring 2(string) 
{
  "x1": 0,
  "children": [
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
}
```

which showed that potentially the keys can be array indices. In this case they are all numbers from 0 to n in string format so:

[adding a regular expression to match numbers](http://jsfiddle.net/wf_bitplan_com/znjp3d7a/13/) fixed the issue

```
function replacer(key,value) { 
  if (value!==null) {
    if (fieldWhiteList.includes(key)) 
      return value;
    if (key.match('[0-9]+'))
      return value;
  }
  console.log('ignoring '+key+'('+typeof (key)+')');
}
```

with the expected output:

```
ignoring x2(string) 
ignoring x4(string) 
{
  "x1": 0,
  "x3": "xyz",
  "children": [
    {
      "x1": 2,
      "x3": 5
    },
    {
      "x1": 3,
      "x3": 6
    },
    {
      "x1": 4,
      "x3": 7
    }
  ]
}
```